# HashMap vs MultivaluedMap

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm recently into Rest API in java and came across MultivaluedMap. I don't find the advantage  `MultivaluedMap` over HashMap or other classes like `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap`.Please explain the scenario when MultivaluedMap is necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A [`MultivaluedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) is:

> A map of key-values pairs. Each key can have **zero or more values**.

A [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true) is:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to **at most one value**.

So in a `MultivaluedMap` you can insert 0, 1, 2, 3 or more objects related to the same key.

In a `Map` you can insert exactly 1 object related to a key.

This is the difference, **it can be useful if you need to store many values related to a single key**, if you have only one value they are similar.

---

A possibile scenario is a Dictionary where you save all the words related starting with a letter. The keys are A B C... Z and the values are the words.

```
A -> Acid
     Apple 
     August

B -> Banana
     Boat

C -> Car
     Chain

...

Z -> Zebra
```

That can be coded with:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> multiMap = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
multiMap.add("A", "Acid");
multiMap.add("A", "Apple");
multiMap.add("A", "August");
multiMap.add("B", "Banana");
multiMap.add("B", "Boat");
multiMap.add("C", "Car");
multiMap.add("C", "Chain");
multiMap.add("Z", "Zebra");
```

Another scenario is a Map holding all products buyed by a user. The keys are the user id and values are the products.

```
USER1 -> Pizza Margherita
         Pizza Pepperoni

USER2 -> Pizza Margherita

USER3 -> Pizza Margherita
         Pizza Pepperoni
         Pizza Four Cheese
```

Comment: please provide an example by putting multiple value..thanks for your answer really helpful

Comment: @SoaFusion query parameters and form parameters can have duplicate keys with different values. For example `http://foo.com?id=1&id=2&id=3`. You would need a `MultivaluedMap` here to put the key `id` with a list of values, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thank you so much for the real world example